# Removing img tag in lxml

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I have this code:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring

html = "<p><img src='some_pic.jpg' />Here is some text</p>"

doc = fromstring(html)
img = doc.find('.//img')
doc.remove(img)

print tostring(doc)
```

And the output is: `<p></p>`

Why does removing the img tag also remove the text following it? In other words, why isn't the result printed out:`<p>Here is some text</p>`
How can I just remove that tag and not remove the text? Note, I get the same result even if I include an explicit closing tag on the img, i.e.:

```
html = "<p><img src='some_pic.jpg'></img>Here is some text</p>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Here is some text` text is an `img` tag's `tail` - it is a part of an element and it is being removed with an element.

To preserve the `tail` - assign it to `img` parent's text:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring

html = "<p><img src='some_pic.jpg' />Here is some text</p>"

doc = fromstring(html)
img = doc.find('.//img')
parent = img.getparent()
parent.text = img.tail
doc.remove(img)

print tostring(doc)
```

prints:

```
<p>Here is some text</p>
```